# Gephi - open networkx with colored nodes

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

I have a rather large network (34594 nodes and 3897 edges). I created a Networkx network in Python and gave the nodes a color based on the label of the node. The label links the node to 5 countries based on the beginning letters. In Python, this all worked out fine, but for visualization purposes I exported the file (.gexf) to open it in Gephi. However, when I open it again, it does not have the colors anymore. There is a plug-in (Give color to nodes), however, it seems that I have to change the color manually, node per node. You can import a spreadsheet, which I initially wanted to do, and use as some type of look-up table. However, this is not possible, and you can only import the nodes from there, but those are not linked to the network.

Does anybody has any insights on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `networkx`, I will propose a very simple script that iterates all nodes and colors every node as *blue*.

```
import networkx as nx

# Construct a simple line graph
G = nx.path_graph(4)

for v in nx.nodes(G):
    # Set the viz attribute for each node
    G.nodes[v]["viz"] = {} 
    # Set the color to blue
    G.nodes[v]["viz"]["color"] = {"a":0, "r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 255}
     
# output a sample graph
nx.write_gexf(G, 'test.gexf')
```

The line `G.nodes[v]["viz"] = {}`, is required to add the `viz` dictionary to each node, and then we add the ARGB value of each node. In this example `a=0` and `RGB=(0,0,255)` or, simply speaking, blue.

The script is based on [networkx documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.gexf.write_gexf.html), with some small changes. Adding colors should also be possible with an adaptation of `nx.setNodeAttibutes`, as shown [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html#networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes). It is just that the GEXF format, needs the `viz` attribute, and then the the corresponding `color`.